# Tradeoffs of unpackWARs in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Tin Tomcat there is a setting [unpackWARs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation) to either explode the WARs or just run from an unexploded WAR. What are the tradeoffs here? Why would you choose unpacking or choose not unpacking?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following differences:

- Startup time. Unpacking makes a delay of a few seconds. This has obviously had a bigger impact in the past (late nineties?) when this feature was designed.
- Disk space. Again, this could have made bigger difference in late nineties.
- Ability to customize files after unpacking (either by the webapp itself or by an external script) -- this is *much* easier if the file is exploded.
- Picking up the rubbish. If a .war has been exploded, deploying another version of the same webapp might miss to clean the folder.

I would argue that it in the enterprise world is much more common these days to provide an *entire stack*  which means that companies don't just ship `.war`s but application servers (such as Tomcat) or even entire disk images (not necessarily .iso, could also be e.g. EC2 images). So the significance of `unpackWARs` has dwindled.